# ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from '__main__' in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I made a simple web app but I got this:

My urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.home,name='home')
```

```
(test) C:\Users\abc\projects\amar>C:/Users/abc/envs/test/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/abc/projects/amar/f1/urls.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/abc/projects/amar/f1/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from '__main__' 
  (c:/Users/abc/projects/amar/f1/urls.py)
```

In views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

And in settings.py template, I also mention path:

```
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
   'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to run urls.py directly. That won't work at all.

Start the server by running `manage.py runserver`.

Comment: it will work but that error still not gone  and every time they show same but server work well